# Hyphenating underscored Clojure map keys for database results

Tags: database, dictionary, clojure, hyphenation

I'm using [SQLingvo](https://github.com/r0man/sqlingvo) and [clojure.jdbc](https://github.com/niwibe/clojure.jdbc) to access a PostgreSQL database.

Data is being returned as underscored maps, e.g. `{:created_at "some date"}`, when I expect hyphenated keywords like `:created-at`. Is there an easy way to marshall these maps back into their hyphenated versions?

Answer (score 4):

I've used `clojure.walk/postwalk` to accomplish this.

```
(defn transform-keys
  "Recursively transforms all map keys in coll with the transform-key fn."
  [transform-key coll]
  (letfn [(transform [x] (if (map? x)
                           (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [(transform-key k) v]) x))
                           x))]
    (walk/postwalk transform coll)))
```

The first argument is a function that takes the existing key and returns the new one. In your case, you can convert the keyword to a string, replace the underscores with hyphens, and convert it back into a keyword.

https://gist.github.com/jeremyheiler/fe9256e540121e771285

Comment: Nowadays also worth looking at [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) by Nathan Marz.

Comment: Note that this is _very_ similar to `clojure.walk/keywordize-keys` which you can take as an inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to provide `{:identifiers #(.replace % \_ \-)}` in options when you make a query, just as it is in `clojure.java.jdbc`.